How to apply relativedelta or DateOffset to a column
Follow up from this question, what if the relative amount is not constant and should come from a column like below? Instead of a constant 2 months, I need to get the birthday some years later. Moreover, it should be able to account for the case of 29 Feb if exists. How to modify the code, please?
df['dob'] + relativedelta(years=df['someint'])
df['dob'] + pd.DateOffset(years=df['someint'])

Running above line will lead to the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
